# Parsing out xml column(varchar) within a table which needs to create a view

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2012, xml-parsing

```
@xml =      N'<School>
    <Name>
        <Id>123456</ID>
    </Name>
    <Grade> 
        <FirstGrade>80</FirstGrade>
    </Grade> 
            </School>',
```

This part above is a varchar column in Schooltable which contain several other columns. I just want to parse schooldataxml which contains xml and formatted as varchar.

This is what I have tried

```
create view school as

 select CAST(CAST(schooldataxml as nvarchar(max)) as XML).query('school/Name/Id') Col
    from schooltable
```

Here I am trying to cast it as cast statement however it doesn't take out the html tags. I have tried nodes too but got no success

I am getting this

```
<Id>123456</ID>
```

I want to get this for each row in a new column in my new view

```
123456
```

Please note that I need to parse every row into my new column one by one. So the next value that needs to be parse out is different- dynamic values.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to StackOverflow.

Note this code:

```
DECLARE @xml XML =
N'<School>
    <Name>
        <ID>123456</ID>
    </Name>
    <Grade> 
        <FirstGrade>80</FirstGrade>
    </Grade> 
</School>';

SELECT @xml.query('/School/Name/ID'); --<< THIS
SELECT @xml.query('(/School/Name/ID/text())[1]'); --<< NEEDS TO BE THIS
SELECT @xml.value('(/School/Name/ID/text())[1]','VARCHAR(100)'); -- EVEN BETTER
```

With [query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/xml/query-method-xml-data-type?view=sql-server-ver15) you need to specify the node type in your XPath expression; the default behavior is to return an XML node.

For what you are doing, the [value](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/xml/value-method-xml-data-type?view=sql-server-ver15) method will likely yield better performance.

**Against a table:**

```
DECLARE @schooltable TABLE (schooldataxml XML);
INSERT @schooltable VALUES(
N'<School>
    <Name>
        <ID>123456</ID>
    </Name>
    <Grade> 
        <FirstGrade>80</FirstGrade>
    </Grade> 
</School>'),(
N'<School>
    <Name>
        <ID>555444</ID>
    </Name>
    <Grade> 
        <FirstGrade>90</FirstGrade>
    </Grade> 
</School>');

SELECT SomeId = s.schooldataxml.value('(/School/Name/ID/text())[1]','VARCHAR(100)')
FROM   @schooltable AS s;
```

**Returns:**

```
SomeId
----------
123456
555444
```

Comment: Thanks.. It seems like text () works for extracting the data.